# checkbox .checked property always false

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, checked

for some reason this code doesn't properly get the checked property of the checkbox, instead it always false. I was expecting it to show whether the checkbox was checked. What am I missing? Thanks

```js
const clickArray = document.querySelectorAll("input")
const changeStyle = style => {
  return (() => console.log(style))
}
clickArray.forEach(
  (item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', changeStyle(item.checked))
  }
)
```

```html
<label for="chk1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1">
        Bold
    </label>
<label for="chk2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="chk2">
        Italic
    </label>
<label for="chk3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="chk3">
        Underline
    </label> const click
```

Comment: what is click array ?

Comment: sorry the begin part wasn't put in, it's fixed now

Comment: Check `e.target.checked` inside `onClick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting `item.checked` at the time you call `changeStyle`, which is when you're adding the event listener, not when the event occurs.

Instead of passing `item.checked` to `changeStyle`, pass `item`, and have `changeStyle` get the `checked` property.

```js
const clickArray = document.querySelectorAll("input")
const changeStyle = element => {
  return (() => console.log(element.checked))
}
clickArray.forEach(
  (item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', changeStyle(item))
  }
)
```

```html
<label for="chk1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1">
        Bold
    </label>
<label for="chk2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="chk2">
        Italic
    </label>
<label for="chk3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="chk3">
        Underline
    </label> const click
```

Comment: So item.checked is passed by value?

Comment: Function arguments are always passed by value in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLVED**, In your case the function call is loosing the context, As you are using eventlisteners, use event to perform any checks, not  element, as it will bind the old context of the element to the function.

```
clickArray = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const changeStyle = style => {
  console.log(style);
}
clickArray.forEach(
  (item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (e) { changeStyle(e.target.checked) })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1">
```

will report `.checked = false` because it does not have the attribute `checked`. If you want to have the `.checked = true` the element should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1"  checked="checked">
```

Notice: an `<input>` of `type=checkbox` has no use of the attribute `value`. Thus, it is ignored. It has no effect on its `.checked` property.

Comment: The value is used when submitting the form to a server. The checked boxes will be submitted as `name=value`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping *changeStyle()* in side of an anonymous function:

```js
var clickArray = document.querySelectorAll("input")
const changeStyle = style => {
  console.log(style);
}
clickArray.forEach(
    (item, index) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(){ changeStyle(this.checked)})
    }
)
```

```html
<label for="chk1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1">
    Bold
</label>
<label for="chk2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="chk2">
    Italic
</label>
<label for="chk3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="chk3">
    Underline
</label>
```